# Dropwizard application integration test, DropwizardAppRule port is null

Tags: dropwizard

I am fairly new to Dropwzard so feel free to guide me incase I am not doing something right. Here is my scenario.

I am writing an integration test for the whole application (Which runs okay) following a tutorial from a book. However my test runs but not the full app on the specified port. Below is my test

```
 import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.glassfish.jersey.client.authentication.HttpAuthenticationFeature;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.Test;

import demo.basicapi.configuration.BasicConfiguration;
import demo.basicapi.domain.Contact;
import io.dropwizard.testing.junit.DropwizardAppRule;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class AppTest extends TestCase {

    private Client client;
    private Contact dummyClient = new Contact(0, "Jane", "Doe", "+987654321");

    @ClassRule
    public static final DropwizardAppRule<BasicConfiguration> RULE = new DropwizardAppRule<BasicConfiguration>(
            App.class, "config.yaml");

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
        // Set the credentials to be used by the client
        HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("admin", "password");
        client.register(feature);
    }

    @Test
    public void testcreateAndRetrieveContact() {
        // Create a new contact by performing the appropriate http request (POST)

        WebTarget target = client.target(String.format("http://localhost:%d/contact", RULE.getLocalPort()));
        Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(Entity.entity(dummyClient, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        // Check that the response has the appropriate response code (201)
        assertEquals(response.getStatus(), 201);

    }

}
```

However when I run the test, I get a Null pointer exception when retrieving the port number

```
RULE.getLocalPort() // This returns null in my test.

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.274 sec <<< FAILURE!
testcreateAndRetrieveContact(demo.basicapi.AppTest)  Time elapsed: 0.132 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:221)
    at io.dropwizard.testing.DropwizardTestSupport.getLocalPort(DropwizardTestSupport.java:249)
    at io.dropwizard.testing.junit.DropwizardAppRule.getLocalPort(DropwizardAppRule.java:180)
    at demo.basicapi.AppTest.testcreateAndRetrieveContact(AppTest.java:41)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Also, I am a bit concerned that if I play around with this line, I dont get any error whatsoever, It doesn't matter the name of config file,

```
@ClassRule
    public static final DropwizardAppRule<BasicConfiguration> RULE = new DropwizardAppRule<BasicConfiguration>(
            App.class, "config.yaml");
```

Changing the name of the .yaml file to something nonexisted does not throw any other error in the tests.

I am using Dropwizard version 1.3.12, Is there anything I could change to be succesful. I for now I am not focussing on separate representation tests, but feel free to advise. Thanks.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-testing</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```